# How can I make my EditText five lines high without using android:inputType="textMultiLine"?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinput

I want to have a EditText view that is five lines high.  I want it five lines high for visual appeal reasons only (so that it does not appear cramped).  The code below does not work, the EditText appears only one line high.

I have tried multilinetext and it works visually, however I want to abandon it as I want the virtual keyboard to say "Next" (rather than have the enter key that is automatically provided with multiline text)

How can I make my EditText box bigger?  Alternatively, how can I use the imeOption "actionNext" with multiline text?

***This code does not work...***

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEdit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:lines="5"  //this has no effect!
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        style="@style/dialogInput" />
```

Comment: did you try to set layout_height to specific pixel height? ex) 50dp

Answer (score 6):

Change:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

to:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Works for me!

Answer (score 3):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEdit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:lines="5"  //this has no effect!
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        style="@style/dialogInput"
        android:singleLine="false" />  

android:singleLine="false" will make editText to support multiple lines
```

Comment: I tested this and it does not work. It results in a single line with a next button. Not a multiline with next button.

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, you can try to use a line-break on text string to display, this is the tip: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/set-line-break-in-textview/

and of course, you must set:

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

To:

```
android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
```

If that doesn't work then change:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

To:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

and delete:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
style="@style/dialogInput"
```